# Could not open sample.fxml Javafx in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

When I try to open an fxml file in JavaFx scenebuilder from within Intellij, it gives me the following error:
Could not open 'sample.fxml'
open operation has failed. Make sure that the chosen file is a valid FXML document. Please see the images below to see the foto of error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you use images, please make sure to include them in your question, not just the links. This way, its easier to read the question.

Comment: sure, but you have to keep in mind that as a new user, stackoverflow does not allow the direct posting of images for me.

Comment: No worries, i will do the edit then :)

Comment: Thanks Glains :) but nobody has answered my question yet, I'm still stuck in the problem :(

Comment: sorry, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The comment syntax you're using isn't valid for an fxml document. Instead of:

```
// your comment here
```

use this:

```
<!-- your comment here -->
```